# How to attach raw SQL to an existing Rails ActiveRecord chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rule builder that ultimately builds up ActiveRecord queries by chaining multiple `where` calls, like so:

```
Track.where("tracks.popularity < ?", 1).where("(audio_features ->> 'valence')::numeric between ? and ?", 2, 5)
```

Then, if someone wants to sort the results randomly, it would append `order("random()")`.

However, given the table size, `random()` is extremely inefficient for ordering, so I need to use Postgres TABLESAMPLE-ing.

In a raw SQL query, that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "tracks" TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1) LIMIT 250;
```

Is there some way to add that `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1)` to the existing chain of ActiveRecord calls? Putting it inside a `where()` or `order()` doesn't work since it's not a WHERE or ORDER BY function.

Comment: I looked into it a bit and adding completely new structures to `Arel::Nodes::SelectManager` seems pretty hard to do. Especially in this case as TABLESAMPLE has to be on the end of the query. You might want to trying asking on the rails core developer mailing list as they might have some insights into the deep dark inner workings of Arel.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):004:0> Track.from('"tracks" TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1)')
  Track Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: To append to the existing chain this won't work though maybe something like `Trak.from("#{existing_chain.to_sql}  TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1)")` but that will break additional chaining so it would be extremely order dependent

Comment: There are scenarios where it's doing JOINs on other columns, so if TABLESAMPLE is inserted before the JOIN, then it basically kills the JOIN.

Comment: @Shpigford would there be additional ordering involved or just the table sample no order

Comment: @engineersmnky No additional ordering. Just TABLESAMPLE.

Comment: @engineersmnky Is it possible `arel` is the wrong method name? It's spitting out `SELECT  "tracks".* FROM #<Arel::Nodes::TableAlias:0x00007fc02254ec48> TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1)` (and in turn, throwing an error).

Comment: I knew it couldn't have been that simple. You can get the "froms" with `self.arel.froms.map {|f| f.try(:name) || f }` but it will still break if a join clause is added.

Comment: I guess as a weird workaround you could do a subquery - `Track.where(id: Track.from('"tracks" TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.1)')).` - it leaves the "outer scope" untouched but it I don't know how it will perform.